# How to make a header clickable in react table

Tags: javascript, react-table

I'm using react table and I want to make one of my headers clickable, so when the user clicks it a drop down menu will appear. I know you can add a custom function for `onRowClick` like.

```
const onRowClick = cell => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      // do something here
    }
  }
}
```

But is there a way to do that in the header cell only? Are you supposed to add it to your columns, like.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
  {
    Header: 'Header',
    accessor: 'header',
    onClick: () => // do something
  }
])
```

Comment: doesn't the https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/kitchen-sink show an example like that for "Status"?

Comment: See I don't want a drop down menu in the header cell. I want to be able to click the icon I have in the cell and then trigger a dropdown menu if that makes sense. @ChristianFritz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a custom function like `onRowClick`, but for your headers, here is one.

```
const onHeaderClick = () => {
      return {
        onClick: () => {
          // do something
        },
      };
  };
```

then pass it down to your table component

```
<Table
    clickableHeader={onHeaderClick}
/>
```

then in your table component you can call it in your `th` component like this

```
<th
{...clickableHeader(column)}
>
```