# How to make a clickable header in react table

Tags: reactjs, dom

Im curious how one goes about making a header clickable while working with tables in react. Ive been digging through posts and forums for some time to no avail.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     cars: [
       {
          manufacturer: "Toyota",
          model: "Rav4",
          year: 2008,
          stock: 3,
          price: 8500,
        },

       {
         manufacturer: "Toyota",
         model: "Camry",
         year: 2009,
         stock: 2,
         price: 6500,
      },
      {
         manufacturer: "Toyota",
         model: "Tacoma",
      year: 2016,
      stock: 1,
      price: 22000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "BMW",
      model: "i3",
      year: 2012,
      stock: 5,
      price: 12000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Chevy",
      model: "Malibu",
      year: 2015,
      stock: 2,
      price: 10000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Honda",
      model: "Accord",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 1,
      price: 9000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Hyundai",
      model: "Elantra",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 2,
      price: 7000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Chevy",
      model: "Cruze",
      year: 2012,
      stock: 2,
      price: 5500,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Dodge",
      model: "Charger",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 2,
      price: 16000,
    },

    {
         manufacturer: "Ford",
         model: "Mustang",
         year: 2009,
         stock: 1,
          price: 8000,
        },
      ],
    };
 }
render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <Table clickableHeader={onHeaderClick} data={this.state.cars} />
   </div>
 );
}
}

const onHeaderClick = () => {
      return {
        onClick: () => {
          return <p>hi</p>;
        },
      };
  };

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const tableHeads = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return (
      <table border="0">
        <thead>
           <th>Manufacturer</th>
           <th>Model</th>
           <th {...clickableHeader(column)} >Year</th>
           <th>Stock</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Option</th>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
         {this.props.data.map((value, key) => (
           <tr key={key}>
              <td>{value.manufacturer}</td>
              <td>{value.model}</td>
              <td>{value.year}</td>
              <td>{value.stock}</td>
              <td>{value.price}</td>
              <button>Increment</button>
          </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

However, this produces nothing. Perhaps I've implemented it wrong.
When clickable header is taken out, this is what I get

[image: graph]

My goal is to make the header labled, Year, clickable. It will sort the data in ascending or descending order based on year.

Here is the post I was using as a reference: [How to make a header clickable in react table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906217/how-to-make-a-header-clickable-in-react-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to put all my `<th>` inside of a `<tr>`  that and using `()=> this`  helped a lot.

```
function onHeaderClick(){
      return <p> hi</p>;
  }

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const tableHeads = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return (
      <table border="0">
        <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th onClick={()=> this.onHeaderClick}>Year</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Option</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
         {this.props.data.map((value, key) => (
           <tr key={key}>
              <td>{value.manufacturer}</td>
              <td>{value.model}</td>
              <td>{value.year}</td>
              <td>{value.stock}</td>
              <td>{value.price}</td>
              <td>
                <button>Increment</button>
              </td>

          </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cars: [
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Rav4",
                    year: 2008,
                    stock: 3,
                    price: 8500,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Camry",
                    year: 2009,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 6500,
                },
                {
                    manufacturer: "Toyota",
                    model: "Tacoma",
                    year: 2016,
                    stock: 1,
                    price: 22000,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "BMW",
                    model: "i3",
                    year: 2012,
                    stock: 5,
                    price: 12000,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Chevy",
                    model: "Malibu",
                    year: 2015,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 10000,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Honda",
                    model: "Accord",
                    year: 2013,
                    stock: 1,
                    price: 9000,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Hyundai",
                    model: "Elantra",
                    year: 2013,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 7000,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Chevy",
                    model: "Cruze",
                    year: 2012,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 5500,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Dodge",
                    model: "Charger",
                    year: 2013,
                    stock: 2,
                    price: 16000,
                },

                {
                    manufacturer: "Ford",
                    model: "Mustang",
                    year: 2009,
                    stock: 1,
                    price: 8000,
                },
            ],
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Table clickableHeader={this.onHeaderClick} data={this.state.cars} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    onHeaderClick = (data) => {
        return {
            onClick: () => {
                return <p>hi</p>;
            },
        };
    };
}
class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const tableHeads = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
        return (
            <table border="0">
                <thead>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th onClick={() => this.props.onHeaderClick(data)} >Year</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Option</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.data.map((value, key) => (
                    <tr key={key}>
                        <td>{value.manufacturer}</td>
                        <td>{value.model}</td>
                        <td>{value.year}</td>
                        <td>{value.stock}</td>
                        <td>{value.price}</td>
                        <button>Increment</button>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

Try like this! :>

Comment: I appreciate your comment so I gave it an upvote. Unfortunately, when I attempt to compile this, I get the resulting errors.
https://imgur.com/a/n5resRc